# How do I perform a hardware reset of an x86 machine?

Tags: linux, assembly, embedded, x86, embedded-linux

I've got an application running under Linux on an embedded x86 microcontroller. I want to be guaranteed that I can reset this CPU from the application.

Assume that the kernel and operating system might be compromised at this point, so calling "reboot" or "shutdown" won't work.

Assume I don't have a watchdog timer. Even then, sometimes watchdog timers are called by a daemon (e.g. [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#watchdog) has one)

Is there some inline assembly I can write that will call some register on x86 that will reset the CPU?

Comment: Several methods are proposed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!msg/alt.os.development/raY7nOqF2bA/LB6-wDVm_y8J), but I'm not in a mood to test any of them ;)

Comment: Make the program paint random chars on the screen so user thinks OS is broken and pushes reset button. Easier than getting into ring-0

Comment: Of course not. If there was, that would be a total disaster, allowing any random program to reset the CPU and completely destroy the integrity of the system.

Comment: I've heard about some undocumented instruction (HCF), but I don't think it was for x86, which translates to a single byte opcode (decimal representation 666), which did something like that ;-)

Comment: Ummm ... no ... you can't "completely destroy the integrity of the system" by a sudden powerdown if the root fs is mounted RO. Linux 101, dude ...  How do you think embedded Linux systems like Android phones and routers are set up?

Comment: @MrStinky: Really? Mounting the root filesystem read only will keep the system navigating the plane to its destination or controlling the position of the control rods in a nuclear reactor even if it resets?

Comment: You can buy an IP controlled power strip, then just ping it to force a hard reboot: http://www.amazon.com/Managed-Designed-Manufactured-Synaccess-Networks/dp/B0039OZKPE

Comment: What if the *application* fails and burns down the reactor or crashes the aeroplane? How is a reset any more dangerous than what can be done by the application? An application has control over the whole system i.e. it can set stuff on fire, or crash a plane. A reset simply resets the system and then the application puts it into a known state.
A watchdog is used to asynchronously reset the system. So, by your own logic, having a watchdog is a bad thing (because of mission critical things like nuclear power stations and aeroplanes). 
Can you explain your answer a little bit more?

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking_(fallacy)

Comment: @MrStinky: Modern computers and operating systems isolate applications so that they can't do anything comparable to resetting the system. And CPUs don't have watchdogs that aren't under the control of the operating system for just that reason. Having a watchdog in the CPU that an application could trigger would *definitely* be a bad thing because of mission critical things.

Comment: @aland, It turns out that my x86 microcontroller (Vortex86DX) has a bit in a register on an ioport that does a system reset. So it's as simple as `ioperm( 0x92, 1, 1); outb( 0x01, 0x92 );` to perform an instant hardware reset.

Comment: @aland, silly me, I should have looked here first: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c This is how the Linux kernel does it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to guarantee that this will happen from userspace (i.e., your application) would be to write a system call that executes any one of the functions in arch/x86/kernel/reboot.c depending on the severity of the situation.

However, if you end up going that route, you might want to make sure that other applications aren't able to make that system call!